# How to --enable-dom without recompiling PHP?

Tags: php

From the output of `phpinfo()`, `--disable-dom` are included the configure command. How do I change it to `--enable-dom` without recompiling PHP?

**Edit**: I'm using Fedora 10. The PHP i'm using is the one that came with it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just install the package named **php-xml**, which **provides the *php-dom* support**.

You can find a list of downloads at http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/10503222/com/php-xml-5.2.6-5.i386.rpm.html

Make sure to adjust configs in order to actually load the modules:

```
/etc/php.d/dom.ini
/etc/php.d/xmlreader.ini
/etc/php.d/xmlwriter.ini
/etc/php.d/xsl.ini
```

and restart apache.

Comment: Looks like installing php-xml does the trick for dompdf. It is now creating the pdf, but the error is still there.

Comment: please edit your post adding some output. Detail the error you got.

Comment: Are you sure you have loaded the extendsion in your php.ini and restarted apache too ?

Comment: I'm getting the same error, but the pdf is now being created. I haven't modified php.ini yet. Which extension do I need to load in php.ini?

Comment: Wait, I didn't need to modify php.ini. It works perfectly now. Thanks!

Comment: +1 again for the configs!

Comment: BTW, it was working even though I haven't modified the `.ini` files. What does it do?

Comment: I guess they was already ok :)

Comment: For anyone that comes across this and installed the IUS php53 package, you would install php53-xml.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot - these are compile-time options.

Unless you find another pre-compiled PHP distribution that is compatible with your setup (which you don't detail in your question).

Unless of course the functions that you are looking for are implemented in other ways too, say a set of functions in a php script file that you can `include()` into your scripts.

Comment: You can simply search a package that provide it as a shared object. Every modern distribution has such a package for a great number of PHP extensions.

Answer (score 2):

I installed php-xml with YUM (CentOS)

**sudo yum install php-xml**

Restart Apache

**sudo service httpd restart**

Everything works fine

Comment: Note that if you have PHP 5.3 installed, you may need to use this instead:
`sudo yum install php53-xml`

Comment: In my case there was also an issue with the `php-common` dependency not being met (wrong version I guess?). The following commands fixed it: `$ rpm -e --nodeps php-common
# warning: /etc/php.ini saved as /etc/php.ini.rpmsave
$ yum install php53-xml
# restore the original php.ini
$ cp /etc/php.ini.rpmsave /etc/php.ini`

Answer (score 0):

you could download the SRPM for PHP. Change the spec file so that it has --enable-dom then remake the RPM using rpmbuild tools.

See [This Site](http://bradthemad.org/tech/notes/patching_rpms.php) as an example of patching and rebuild a SRPM.