# Reconfiguring or recompiling a PHP installation originally installed via yum

Tags: php, yum, php.ini

I'm a programmer who currently does not have a sysadmin. I have a decent, but not in-depth, knowledge of Linux OSes such as RedHat and Scientific Linux.

Right now I'm writing some programs in PHP for a webserver running on Scientific Linux 6.3 which is hosting a live site. PHP was installed via `yum`, version 5.3.3-14.el6_3

The website the server is hosting is running on a content management system written in php, and it works just fine. However, my programs use the DOMDocument and Curl libraries which, according to the "Configure Command" section of phpinfo(), were not installed. This is preventing my scripts from running correctly. I see the following parameters in that section: `--disable-dom` and `--without-curl`

Is there some way I can enable the curl and DOMDocument functionality without recompiling PHP from the command line? Perhaps there is a `yum` command?

If I do need to manually recompile PHP, what is the best way to go about doing this, considering that the current PHP was installed via `yum`?

Comment: I found the answer here: [link](http://serverfault.com/questions/66189/how-to-enable-dom-without-recompiling-php). Turns out I just needed to restart Apache after running yum install dom-xml. Thanks @KM01 !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `yum` (-: Here is an example

```
yum install php-mcrypt
```

This will install php's mcrypt module and any related dependencies.

You can look for the libraries/modules to install by running

```
yum search name_of_library_or_module
```

HTH

Comment: That does help! I ran `yum install php-xml` and it says it's already installed. That's good. I see that the `dom.so` module is installed...perhaps I just need to make PHP load it somehow. I'm researching that now. Thanks!

Comment: A ha! In phpinfo(), it's saying that it's parsing additional .ini files. `dom.ini` is not on that list, but when I looked in the `/etc/php.d/` directory where these additional .ini files are located, and I see `dom.ini` in there. Now I just have to figure out why PHP is not loading it.

Comment: Restart your web server ... ?